# Get role of the user who created a custom resource in a kubernetes operator

Tags: kubernetes, controller, rbac

**Scenario**: A user creates a custom resource. The controller can create resources of different types (eg. Deployment, Service, etc).

**Usecase**: The controller should only create those resources for which the user has the permissions. For instance, if the user doesn't have permission to view/edit deployment object, the controller shouldn't create it either.

**Question**: How does the controller get to know who created the custom resource? And then get the roles associated with that user?

If it matters, I am using kubebuilder to write the controller.

Comment: you better seperate this using namespaces, or rbac on that custom resource